# controller function use with ajax

Tags: ajax

I have one controller like as below .

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\users\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;


class UsersController extends ControllerBase {


  public function getList() {
    $time = time();
    $data = array();
    $response = $data = $result = null;

      // add all the data in one multiple dim. array
      $data['title'] = 'Example to consume REST API of User List';
      $data['users'] = $result->list;
      $data['form_data'] = $result->form_data;

      // display the content in the middle section of the page
      $build = array(
        '#theme' => 'users_list', // assign the theme [users-list.html.twig]
        '#title' => 'Example to consume REST API', 
        '#pagehtml' => 'API URL : api/users/list ',
        '#data' => $data
      ); 
    }


    return $build;
  }
}
```

this above function is called and render the HTML in the middle of the page in HTML format where page URL is call as per defined in routing file (http://siteurl.com/user-list).
I want to use this HTML output in ajax request which will call the same function through ajax instead of page url.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\ajax\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class AjaxController extends ControllerBase {

  public function call_ajax(){

      //  my target is like as below
       $op = Drupal\Core\Controller\UsersController()->getList();
       return $op;
  }
}
```

Q) Is there any way to get the output of getList() in HTML format in ajax callback?

Comment: Did you try [render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/render/8.2.x) function? While returning variable `$op`, pass it through `render()` function.
eg: `return render($op);`

Answer (score 8):

> **WARNING: The following code contains serious security vulnerabilities, and should not be used in a production site without modification.**

After lots of searching finally, I got the solution.
I would like to share this.

AjaxController.php

```
namespace Drupal\ajax\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class AjaxController extends ControllerBase {

  public function call_ajax($controller,$function){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $r = array();
    $r['html'] = null;
    
    $class = "\\Drupal\\".$controller."\\Controller\\".ucfirst($controller)."Controller";
    
    $obj = new $class();
    
    if(method_exists($obj,$function)){
      $r['html'] = render($obj->$function());
    }
    return new JsonResponse($r);
  }
 
}
```

ajax.routing.yml

```
ajax.call:
  path: '/call/ajax/{controller}/{function}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\ajax\Controller\AjaxController::call_ajax'
    _title: 'Get List'
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($a){
    $a.ajax({
        url: "call/ajax/users/getList", 
        method :'GET',
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(result){
          $a(".region-content").html(result.html);
        }
    });
})
```

Now I have to just pass the controller and function name to call the function using ajax.

The main purpose to use this way is reusability of controller functions.

Comment: This is a neat solution, but without checking the list of allowed controllers and functions you open every function from every controller up to the public.